# I want to serve files from a folder with webob

Tags: python, webob

I want to use `webob.static.DirectoryApp`. I just can't figure out how to do it:

From the example at http://docs.webob.org/en/latest/file-example.html my router looks like:

```
class Router(object):
    def __init__(self, static_path=None):
        self.routes = []
        self.static_path = static_path if static_path is not None else os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__)), 'static')
        self.static_app = DirectoryApp(self.static_path)

    def add_route(self, template, controller, **vars):
        if isinstance(controller, basestring):
            controller = load_controller(controller)
        self.routes.append((re.compile(template_to_regex(template)),
                            controller,
                            vars))

    def __call__(self, environ, start_response):
        req = Request(environ)
        for regex, controller, vars in self.routes:
            match = regex.match(req.path_info)
            if match:
                req.urlvars = match.groupdict()
                req.urlvars.update(vars)
                return controller(environ, start_response)

        return exc.HTTPNotFound()(environ, start_response)
```

To create the application to serve:

```
def create_app():
    router = Router()

    #router.add_route('/', controller='app.controllers.default:index')
    router.add_route('/', controller=default.index)

    return router
```

This serves routes to my added controllers fine. I also added a `self.static_app`.

I just have no idea how to use it to serve static files from the `static`-folder! Can someone please enlighten me?

Comment: can't you just use something like router.add_route('/static', DirectoryApp(path)) ? You may also have to use req.path_info_pop() before the controller is called to get the real path needed by the DirectoryApp

Comment: Yup! That put me on the right track!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @gawel wrote the answer is to add a route with DirectoryApp as the controller. There is another thing to notice for it to work directly from the example.

The extension `template_to_regex` in the example is adding a `$` to the forcing us to write a route expression that covers the entire url to catch. The `canbewhatever` is never used and can be whatever. The important thing is the regex after the variable.

The add_route should look something like this:

```
router.add_route('/static{canbewhatever:.*}', controller=static_app)
```